# How to insert from two tables into one at the same time?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So, guys...

I have two tables now, one called nobooks with the id of 4 authors that didn't write books and one called noauthors, with with the id of 4 books that don't have an author, and I need to insert them at a third table called authorship, one id_author for one id_title, I've tried something like this:

```
insert into authorship (ID_Author,ID_Title) select * from nobooks, noauthors
```

But it didn't worked, it inserted the 4 id_titles for each id_author, and I don't know anymore what to do, so I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `union` to insert `id, title` from both tables.

```
insert into authorship (ID_Author,ID_Title)
select t1.id, t1.title from (select id, title from nobooks
union all
select id, title from noauthors) as t1;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't worked, error 1136: column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use Union Instead Of Normal Query

```
insert into authorship (ID_Author,ID_Title) 
select id,id from nobooks
union
select id,id from noauthors
```

DB FIDDLE LINK
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60fe37c15112fccec304ae079b33df2a

Answer (score 0):

insert into authorship (ID_Author,ID_Title) 
select id,'nobooks' from nobooks
union
select id,'noauthors' from noauthors